# Are there different definitions of "merge"?

Tags: merge

The `merge` tool in ArcGIS ArcToolbox is used to combine two layers, but it seems that there is also a Merge option under Modify Features that is used to combine and dissolve adjacent features within a layer (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/merge-features-into-one-feature.htm).

Clearly the term is used at least two different ways, but are there two different technical definitions for "merge" within the context of GIS, or is one of these a less formal use of the term?

Comment: At the simplest level, you've articulated it yourself... the merge tool is to combine layers, the merge function in the Editor toolbar is to combine features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the same word is being used for two different tasks, the Merge under the editor toolbar is more like a "dissolve" operation on geometry boundaries, which is more like the behaviour of the Dissolve geoprocessing tool. Just one of those idiosyncrasy you have to live with.

Answer (score 0):

In cartography there is the following notion

1) "summary of typical objects" (docking of typical objects), this means that the map object can be cut by the border of the map sheet (a certain scale), in this case the left map object is reduced (joined) with the right map object , to make one object without violations, which physically consists of two objects,

2) "stitching (merging)" of the same type of map object, this means that the left map object is merged (merged) with the right map sheet object, the result is one stitched map object,

P.S. 
as long as there is a sheet method for creating and updating map nomenclatures, these two concepts will be coexist, I hope in the future people will switch to an object-oriented approach, which means that the database will store the entire one object, for example, the Mississippi River from source to mouth, together with its tributaries as one object, with many semantics and characteristics

I to think that the Google translator is not much changed the meaning of my words, something like this: -) ..